# Test sparksql query

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I have a Dataframe that I want to run a simple query on like this:

```
def runQuery(df: DataFrame, queryString: String): DataFrame = {

    df.createOrReplaceTempView("myDataFrame")
    spark.sql(queryString)

}
```

Where queryString can be something like

```
"SELECT name, age FROM myDataFrame WHERE age > 30"
```

But I'd really like to know ahead of time whether the query will work without having to throw an Exception. For instance, what if `df` doesn't have the columns `name` and `age`? I want to write something like this to handle it:

```
def runQuery(df: DataFrame, queryString: String): DataFrame = {

    if (/*** df and queryString are compatible ***/) {
        df.createOrReplaceTempView("myDataFrame")
        spark.sql(queryString)
    } else {
        spark.createDataFrame(sc.emptyRDD[Row], df.schema)
    }

}
```

Is there a way to check this in an 'if' statement?

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't worry to much about exceptions. Just wrap it with `Try`:

```
import scala.util.Try
import org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.encoders.RowEncoder

def runQuery(df: DataFrame, queryString: String): DataFrame = Try {
  df.createOrReplaceTempView("myDataFrame")
  df.sparkSession.sql(queryString)
}.getOrElse(df.sparkSession.emptyDataset(RowEncoder(df.schema)))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check all the columns present in dataframe or not with triggering spark job

```
  def runQuery(df: DataFrame, queryString: String): DataFrame = 
    if(Array("name", "age", "address").forall(df.columns.contains)) {
      df.createOrReplaceTempView("myDataFrame")
      df.sparkSession.sql(queryString)
    } else {
      df.sparkSession.emptyDataset(RowEncoder(df.schema))
    }
```

you can use `df.schema` to match datatype as well